# Search document from document library usin CAML query

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, caml-query, search-scope

I have document library which have folder and sub folder. the folder and  sub folder level is  more than 5. like as follow :

```
Document Library
   |-> Folder-1
   |   -> Folder-1-1
   |      -> Folder-1-1-1
   |         -> Folder-1-1-1-1
   |            -> Folder-1-1-1-1-1
   |               -> Document1.doc
   -> Folder-2
   |   -> Folder-2-1
   |      -> Folder-2-1-1
   |         -> Folder-2-1-1-1
   |            -> Folder-2-1-1-1-1
   |               -> Document2.doc
```

now i want a CAML Query that search the document from all folders of document library and list them in grid view. if i search **"men"** then it will display documents in Grid view which contains **"men"** in there **Title Field**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CAML query should look like this:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
         <Value Type='File'>men</Value>
      </Contains>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

And specify the ViewAttribute of SPQuery to Recursive so that documents within folders are also displayed. `oQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";`